# Сбой при регистрации служб SharePoint 2016

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, sharepoint, windows-server-2012

При установке SharePoint 2016 был выбрал вариант "Автономная установка", после установки был запущен "Мастер настройки продуктов Sharepoint". На 5-м этапе установки при регистрации служб появляется ошибка с текстом *"Создано исключение типа Sysyem.ComponentModel.Win32Exception. Дополнительные сведения об исключении: c2wts (.\LocalSystem)"*

[image: сбой при регистрации служб]

Вот кусок с ошибкой в журнале событий:

> 03/29/2018 08:57:06  9  ERR                Сбой при регистрации служб SharePoint.
>   Создано исключение типа System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception. Дополнительные сведения об исключении: c2wts (.\LocalSystem)
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): c2wts (.\LocalSystem)
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.Win32.SPAdvApi32.ChangeServiceConfiguration(String strServiceName, String strAccountName, SecureString sstrPassword, IdentityType identityType, Boolean bDontRestartService)
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProvisioningAssistant.ProvisionProcessIdentity(String strUserName, SecureString secStrPassword, IdentityType identityType, Boolean isAdminProcess, Boolean isWindowsService, Boolean needsLaunchOnBehalfOfPrivileges, String strServiceName, Boolean delayRestartTimer)
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProcessIdentity.ProvisionInternal(SecureString sstrPassword, Boolean isRunningInTimer)
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWindowsServiceInstance.ProvisionCredentials()
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWindowsServiceInstance.Provision(Boolean start)
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPWindowsTokenServiceInstance.Provision()
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstanceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstanceToo, String serviceInstanceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstances(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstancesToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
>      в Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Весь файл: [PSCDiagnostics_3_29_2018_8_56_10_930_1522712547.log](https://www.upload.ee/files/8255396/PSCDiagnostics_3_29_2018_8_56_10_930_1522712547.log.html)

В диспетчере серверов 4 ошибки в службах:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В службах включил Claims to Windows Token Service (c2WTS)**

**Устанавливал SharePoint и под локальной учетной записью админа, и через SQL_Admin, SP_Admin.**

- Сервер: Windows Server 2012 R2.
- База: MSSQL Server 2012

Comment: Автор, какой вопрос вы хотели задать сообществу?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko из-за чего выходит ошибка и как её устранить?

Comment: тогда предлагаю начать с вопроса, а не описания проблем

Comment: да и 2012 SQL Server не совместим с данной версией

Comment: Убедитесь, что соблюдаются все требования к программному обеспечению и оборудованию. Необходима 64-разрядная версия Windows Server 2012 R2. Для размещения баз данных SharePoint также необходима 64-разрядная версия SQL Server 2014 с пакетом обновления 1 (SP1). Дополнительные сведения об этих требованиях (например, о конкретных обновлениях, которые необходимо установить), см. в статье Требования к оборудованию и программному обеспечению для SharePoint Server 2016. https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc262243(v=office.16).aspx